# Dictionary parsing python

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has a key with a list of values . Something like this:

```
{'a': ['a1', 'a2'], 'b': ['b1', 'b2'], 'c': ['c1', 'c2']}
```

My code for building this :

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('abc.csv'))

print(reader)

result = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.items():
        result.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
print(result)

for k,v in result.items():
    print(k,v)
```

I want something like this :

```
{'a' : a1,'b' : b1 , 'c' : c1}

{'a' : a2,'b' : b2 , 'c' : c2}
```

confused as how to do this .

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DictReader` instance is an iterator that already contains the dictionaries that you seek. You would not need to modify the reader, just turn it into a list:

```
import csv

reader = csv.DictReader(open('abc.csv'))
result = list(reader)
```

`result` will be a list containing dictionaries whose keys are the column headers and the values are the associated rows.

Comment: Once , I get the rows as a list , i want to pass these values into a modified dictionary , something like this :                                                                                [{'a' : a1, 'd' : {b' : b1 , 'c' : c1}}]   , but i am not sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: @Gautham You can post this as a new question which has all the details of what you want to do. And the community will help find an answer.